# How to get target S3 bucket file path while wiriting to parquet file in Spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, bigdata, aws-glue

partition_keys has values ['year', 'month'] and after the partition, the file is saved under 's3://s3_bucket/folder_name/gyear=2023/poper=002/' Can Spark give me this path as I cannot hardcode since this is always be changing.

Code:
source_df.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").partitionBy(partition_keys).save(s3_bucket_path)